# Android Studio Facebook: onActivityResult in normal class

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

In order to listen to a facebook login event I must override in my activity the function onActityResult and make a call to facebook's callbackmanager.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So far everything's working.

I'd like to create a static class for facebook that handles facebook callbacks, such as login, etc.

Is there substitute for onActivityResult in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want another class to handle the activity returning?  Then you have to have onActivityResult of the activity that calls startActivityForResult call into your facebook class.  There's no way to reroute it automatically.